# How to calculate the volume of glass juice?

Tags: c

The radius of the upper part `r1` and lower part `r2` is given. If the height of the glass is `h` and height of the juice is `p` what is the volume of the juice in the glass? For some input-output is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int r1, r2, h, p;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &r1, &r2, &h, &p);
    //for juice height p we will find out the radius r3 
    float r3 = ((r1 * p) / h);  //calculating r3 by percentage formula
    float v = ((M_PI / 3) * 3 * ((r3 * r3) + (r2 * r2) + (r3 + r2)));
    printf("Volume : %f\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** After I changed the all `int` to `double` still for some input output is wrong for an example for input `5 2 3 2` the answer should be `58.64`.

Comment: `(r1*p)/h`: integer division ! Better to use float everywhere here.

Comment: Better use `double` everywhere you need floating-point variables / values!

Comment: @Mohammed: Please do not *fix* the errors in the question, it makes the comments and answers inconsistent. Add an **EDIT:** paragraph with further problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the errors shown in [John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134554/john-bode)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604379/4944425), the posted code is using the wrong formulas to calculate the volume.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// M_PI is not a standard macro
#if !defined(M_PI)
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

int main(void)
{
    // Given the following calculations, I'd use a floating-point type
    // to store the values.
    double r1, r2, h, p;

    // The format specifiers need to be changed accordingly.
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf", &r1, &r2, &h, &p);
    
    // To extimate the radius of top surface of the juice, we can't forget
    // the radius at the bottom of the glass (it's not zero!).
    double r3 = r2 + ((r1 - r2) * p) / h;

    // The volume of the conical frustum can be calculated with a formula different
    // from the posted one and we need to consider the height of the juice.
    double v = M_PI * p * (r3 * r3 + r3 * r2 + r2 * r2) / 3.0;

    printf("Volume : %f\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Integer division yields an integer result - `1/2 == 0`, `5/2 == 2`, etc., so `((r1*p)/h)` is not giving you the right value.

You should declare your inputs as `double` instead of `int` and use `%lf` instead of `%d` to read them:

```
double r1,r2,h,p;
scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&r1,&r2,&h,&p);
```

You'll also want to declare `r3` and `v` as `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: Now i used double and correction my mistake in case of using formula it would be r3*r2 instead of r3+r2 but still for some input the answer is wrong.Like for input 5 2 3 3 the answer is right but for 5 2 3 2 the answer is wrong in this case answer should be 58.64

Comment: @MohammedAbbasUddinTasin: Review your formula for computing the volume again.  I think you have another mistake - it should be `(pi*h)/3 * (R^2 + Rr + r^2)`.  What you have isn't correct.